# Create a list of random numbers

Tags: python, list, random

Assignment (but I wrote my own code):

> Asks the user for size, `L_size`, and creates a list, `L`, with `L_size` real numbers in it. The numbers should be generated randomly (the random generator should be given seed `0`). Import, seed and use the random generator using the following lines:
>
> ```
> import random  # Place it at the top of your program. Do it only once.
>
> random.seed(0) # Place this after the import statements. Seed with 0. Do it only once.
>
> num = random.random() # Call this whenever you want a new, random number.
> ```

So I wrote this code so far.

```
import random
random.seed(0)
num = random.random()
L_size = float(input("Enter a real number: "))
L = []
for L_size in range(num):
    L.append(num)
print (L)
```

It shows me an error:

```
for L_size in range(num):
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer. "
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Think about the error.  Look at the line where the error occurs.  Think about the values you are using in that line of code.

Comment: You are looping over the wrong value. Re-read the question and think more carefully about what should happen.

Comment: `print([random.random() for _ in range(int(input("Enter the size (a positive integer): ")))])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`num = random.random()` should be something like `num = random.randint(1,100)`

`range` takes an `integer` not a `float`

Looking at your question, you should be passing  `L_size`  to `range` not `num`and that should be an `int` not a `float`

```
L_size = int(input("Enter a real number: "))
```

Full code:

```
import random
random.seed(0)
L_size = int(input("Enter a real number: ")) # int to pass to range
L = []
for _ in range(L_size):
    num = random.random() # create random num and append
    L.append(num)
print (L)
```

Or using a list comprehension:

```
import random
random.seed(0)
L_size = int(input("Enter a real number: "))
L = [ random.random() for _ in range(L_size)]
print (L)
```

Comment: The question strictly asks me to use random.random(). So I guess, i can't use range.

Comment: @ZihanIbrahim, your code was just using the values in the wrong place

Comment: yeah, i was considering from a wrong direction. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you ask

```
from random import random, seed

seed(0)
L_size = int(input('Enter the size of the list: '))
L = [ random() for i in range(L_size) ]
print(L)
```

**output**

```
Enter the size of the list: 4
[0.8444218515250481, 0.7579544029403025, 0.420571580830845, 0.25891675029296335]
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to ask the user to enter the size of the list, and then create a list of real numbers; however in your code you are taking the range of some random number.

There are some other problems with your code as well, please see the comments:

```
import random
random.seed(0)
num = random.random()
L_size = float(input("Enter a real number: ")) # this is how big your list should be
L = [] # This is the empty list you are going to add numbers to.
for L_size in range(num): # Here, you need L_size not num
    L.append(num) # here, you need to call random.random() each time,
                  # otherwise you will have a list with the same random
                  # number duplicated
print (L)
```

I hope this helps you with your assignment.